# Symfony run hint kernel.secret parameter not found

Tags: php, symfony

error message:
    The service "uri_signer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter 
   "kernel.secret". Did you mean this: "kernel.charset"?

index.php detail is:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use App\Kernel;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

// 开启调试
Debug::enable();

// 实例化请求
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// 实例化内核
$kernel = new Kernel('dev', true);

$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

app/Kernel.php  detail is:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel{

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
//        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir() . "/config";

//        $loader->load($confDir . "/app.php");
//        $this->set
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $contents = [
            \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
        ];

        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if (isset($envs["all"]) || isset($envs[$this->environment])) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        // code invalid
        $container->setParameter("kernel.secret", "abck");
    }
}
```

composer.json  detail is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.0",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^4.1",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "^4.1",
        "symfony/config": "^4.1",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

next run, show:

[click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3r2D.png)

I used the symonfy component one by one to install and then run, and found that the prompt could not find kernel.secret. I haven't found a solution for Google for a long time, and the online answer is to solve the existing framework of symfony. I hope to tell me how to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: This is just a guess but change Kernel::configureContainer to Kernel::build and see if that helps.  I have never tried using a standalone Kernel.

Comment: afaik `registerContainerConfiguration` loads the configuration files. perhaps you have to load some config (be it a file or env var or something) that contains that parameter?

Answer (score 2):

*There is a new reason to get this error:*

`framework.secret` **used to** be set in `MicroKernelTrait`.

Have a look at the commit [[FrameworkBundle] Remove reference to APP_SECRET in MicroKernelTrait](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/commit/c4bf4ba60dbd259406fa1256fd82e96d0bf1d9db#diff-02cf3db70bae2033c63217ca654c9708) in which this line has been removed:

```php
$container->loadFromExtension('framework', [
   'secret' => '%env(APP_SECRET)%'   //      <== removed
   ...
```

**Solution:**

Set the config by yourself:

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml

framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me on Symfony 6, I just needed a simple Kernel to test my bundle, and I needed to use the `SymfonyFrameworkBundle` in that Kernel, which was complaining about `kernel.secret` not being set because I had no env or config (it's a test micro kernel after all)

So I tried the answers here but it was complaining about the parameter bag being frozen, this is what worked in my case:

```php
class Kernel extends BaseKernel {
//...
    protected function getKernelParameters(): array
    {
        return parent::getKernelParameters() + ['kernel.secret' => '$3cret'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Cerad.

I found that configureContainer is not a method already defined by the parent Kernel, so this method is not called.

So I changed the configureContainer to build and it was ok.

code show as below：

app/kernel.php code is :

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel{

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $contents = [
            \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
        ];

        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if (isset($envs["all"]) || isset($envs[$this->environment])) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    // Modify location
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        $container->setParameter("kernel.secret", "abck");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem. It was caused by the path of my symfony project: it was long and contained spaces and square brackets.

I changed it to a shorter, safer one and it works.